# Invalid regular expression flag b when trying to do `IF` with `$_GET`

Tags: php, if-statement, get

I'm trying to get this piece of code working:

```
<?php
    $color_animation = $_GET['color_animation'];
 if ( $color_animation == "1" ) {
    echo "timer2 = setInterval(function() {
    $('.scar_box').animate( { backgroundColor: '#fee993' }, 1000)
    .animate( { backgroundColor: '#f8d95d' }, 1000); 
    }, 3000);";
}
  ?>
```

But it trows me the error: `Invalid regular expression flag b`

And: `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: color_animation in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php</b> on line <b>117</b><br />`

It doesn't matter what i write into the `$_GET` it still has this problem.

Comment: Instead of following the silencing advise you need to find out why you don't have a `?color_animation=...` URL parameter. Also explain how the regex problem description is related to your code/question.

Comment: I do have `?color_animation=...` in my url and the regex problem is what firefox web-console throws.

Comment: Well, that's an unrelated problem then. Also, is this script for AJAX requests per chance? And please add `print_r($_GET);` for debugging. You need to inspect what parameters you actually received. It's either a typo or RewriteRule, or not the URL you assumed.

Comment: @mario - thank you very much, i didn't knew that i can't use `#` in the values and `print_r` helped me realize that.

Comment: Looks to me like you're passing HTML instead of a regular expression to a function like `preg_match`. Maybe you're passing the notice?

Comment: @toon81 - It has been solved, the problem was that i used a `#` in one of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I missed that bit. But you gave the answer away:

> I don't really know what does CLI means but i run it in the address bar like: `?main_text=Some Text&bgcolor=`**#**`8a7933&button_text=Some man&color_animation=on` (The first $_GET which is main_text always works) – Ricardo 24 mins ago

The raw `#` separates the "fragement identifier" from the URL parameters. You need to use [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) in PHP or [`encodeURIComponent()`](http://www.google.com/search?q=encodeURIComponent%28%29) for Javascript.

Or just use `%23` in its place. (That's the ASCII number equivalent for the `#` number sign.)

Answer (score 2):

`<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: color_animation in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php</b> on line <b>117</b><br />` denotes that you didn't have the $_GET variable set.  Check if it is set first before using it:

```
$color_animation = isset($_GET['color_animation'])?$_GET['color_animation']:'';
```

That should fix the notice.  I am not sure why you are getting that `Invalid regular expression flag b` because you don't use `flag b` in your code at this spot.

Comment: Thank you so much. another problem appeared, it doesn't get's the proper `$_GET` values (it get's nothing actually).

Comment: Are you running it from *CLI*?

Comment: @Shiplu - I don't really know what does CLI means but i run it in the address bar like: `?main_text=Some Text&bgcolor=#8a7933&button_text=Some man&color_animation=on` (The first `$_GET` which is main_text always works)

Comment: @Ricardo CLI = Command Line Interface (ie, did you use Command Prompt on Windows or Terminal on Linux to run the program).  You didn't though from the sound of it.

Comment: @Ricardo the `#` is a special characters in URLs. Escape or remove it. Your query string would, in fact, be interpreted by PHP like so: `?main_text=Some Text&bgcolor=` and the rest is ignored due to the pound.